# ExpressJS And Connect-Mongo Session

Tags: node.js, security, mongodb, session, express

Im using connect-mongo in my ExpressJS apps.

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'some string',
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: mongoose.connection.db
    })
}));
```

What are the other options for session to make the application secure? Im not using `https`.

Comment: having `secure` means using https?

Comment: Well, https will make traffic to/from your site more secure, but it doesn't make your application secure.

Comment: What kind of enhancements in security are you looking for?

Comment: like setting something like session expiry? Is it necessary? THanks